# PHP JQuery Display div fields by Fetching Div Id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting Div Id from Database  and display ID in  form of Checkboxes. I have dynamic values from the data base when dropdown selected and show different values and when I clicked on check it show different input fields each check box has different input fields.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="control-group">
  <!-- // displayresponse id -- get value(Student , Teacher. Subject and each values has specific input fields) from abc page and display here in div -->
  <div class="controls" id="displayresponse">
    CLICK ME --> <input type="checkbox" name="response" id="response" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="displayrow" style="display: none;">
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="displayrow" name="displayrow" value="test1" />
      <input type="text" id="displayrow" name="displayrow" value="test2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
/* //////////////SHOW AND HIDE INPUT FIELDS//// */

/*
$('#response').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#displayrow").show();
  } else {
    $("#displayrow").hide();
  }
});

*/

// If you need this to work for items that are not in the DOM then you should run the click function like this. 

$('body').on("click", "#response",function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#displayrow").show();
  } else {
    $("#displayrow").hide();
  }
});
```

Which part I have  to show different input fields from the database , please guide me or suggest any solution thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the javascript is not coded inside a `<script>` tag

Comment: it just shows and hides input fields, but I have shown the fields by  dynamic id  values from the checkbox accordingly,

Comment: Will the real `displayrow` please stand up?

Comment: In this case i have ID values and fetching values from the Database in form of checkboxes , where i have different checkboxs and every checkbox has different input fields